# Material-ui Datatable Toolbar Special Button

Tags: material-ui

I use the material-ui design library in my project that I am developing with response js. How can I make a special button on the toolbar section of this component to have a cute component from the material table name for this library?

[Material Table Github](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table)

Comment: solution: send to 'isFreeAction: true' in the action buttons sent to the component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution: send to

> isFreeAction: true

in the action buttons sent to the component